# Xcode openframeworks project into visual studio openframeworks

Tags: c++, xcode, visual-studio-2010, openframeworks

Is it possible to convert a project made in xcode with only openframeworks and its libraries to import and work on visual studio with project generator? Also can an exe file and makefile be made that will run when using visual studio?

Searched google but haven't found someone with similar problem.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have OpenFrameworks setup on Windows with Visual Studio you should be able to use the Project Generator to import and browse to your Xcode project:

[image]

The Makefile/addons text files should provide info the the Project Generator to generate a Visual Studio Project.

The main challenge will come from platform specific code.
For example, if the project code or addons make OSX only calls these would need to be ported/converted to Windows variants. Similarly, if the addons have precompiled libraries that are OSX only but have no Windows precompiled libraries you would need to compile those libraries from source (or find Windows compatible addon alternatives and update the code using those addons accordingly)